# executing code from git repository and switching branches

Tags: python, git

I want to compare the results of two versions of an analysis pipeline maintained in git. The pipeline takes quite some time to complete so I want to run them simultaneously.

I have one version installed locally using

```
pip install --no-deps --upgrade -e . --user
```

if I checkout another branch, after launching the pipeline, will this then break the code of the running pipeline?

Comment: if you are using git, then how is this related to pip? (Unless pip is installing from git?). In any case, it would depend on whether your software re-loads itself (for example using `multiprocessing.Process`, `subprocess`, weird `importlib` tricks where it rereads .py files. If the software doesn't do any of that, then once the modules are loaded into memory into the python process, you can change the source code and it won't affect the 2nd run (since code is only loaded once). But can't you just use `virtualenv` to keep the 2 different versions installed simultaneously?

Comment: indeed, the install is done from the git repository. It doesn't do the weird things you mention, although it does call other software which can change versions too. So if these don't change, then it would work if I understand well. Thanks also for suggesting virtualenv. I'll look into using that as an alternative.